# Vue Test Utils - How to mount a component that uses a plugin (in this case vue-unique-id)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I'm trying to test a Vue component that uses the `vue-unique-id` plugin. To instantiate the plugin I use the following code:

```
import UniqueId from 'vue-unique-id';
Vue.use(UniqueId);
new Vue({
    el: `#${element.id}`,
    template: "<App />",
    components: {
        App
    }
});
```

This works without issue. Next I try to mount the component using `vue-test-utils` and `jest`:

```
import currentFilter from "../Current.vue";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

describe("Current Filter", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(currentFilter);
});
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.$id is not a function"
```

This error looks like it's coming from the `vue-unique-id` plugin. So it seems that `jest` and `vue-test-utils` aren't aware of this plugin.

How do I mount the component while telling the mounting function about the `vue-unique-id` plugin?